# Why did I get CS0103 Error - ViewBag doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, viewbag

I have VS 2019 Pro and using .net 5 and C# 9.  I created a project with ASP.NET Core Web App (**without** MVC) template. I got C0103 Error "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context."  Here is an excerpt ***index.cshtml.cs*** code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using ARTS.Client_Models;
using ARTS.Models;
using repository;
:
:

public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    this.VM = new home_VM(this._app_settings);
    ViewBag.User = new User();

    return Page();
}
```

I began to wonder if that is because I am not using MVC? If so, why?

Comment: "ViewBag isn't available in Razor Pages." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Thanks, @Jasen!  I figured ViewBag is no longer in the new version of Razor Pages. I was forced to use ViewData.Model = ... instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor page doesn't support ViewBag, it requires external package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures`. But ViewData is contained in Razor page, so it is a better way to replace it to ViewData.

```
ViewData["User"] = new User();
```

If you have to use ViewBag, you can refer to this [answer](https://forums.asp.net/t/2128012.aspx?Razor%20Pages%20ViewBag%20has%20gone%20).

Comment: I figured. But Thank you, Karney.

Comment: You are welcome, can you accept this answer?